# Show product Group Prices

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I am trying to show the Group prices for each product, a functionality that Magento has but apparently in this theme it does not work, all prices shown are the normal ones. Magento Version 1.9.2.

This is how I load my product views:

```
$_products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addCategoryFilter($newCategory)
    ->setPageSize(3)
    ->setOrder('position', 'ASC')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility' , Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOT`enter code here`H)
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addFinalPrice()
    ->load();
```

Then this is my controller code:

```
foreach ($_products as $_product) {
    $login = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn();
    $productId = $_product->getId();
    $groupPrices = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
    $groupId    = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
    $group      = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load($groupId);

    /* some debug code */
    var_dump($group->getCode());
    $Groupprice = $groupPrices;
    echo $Groupprice;

    if (is_null($groupPrices)) {
        $attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute();
        if ($attribute) {
            $attribute->getBackend()->afterLoad($_product);
            $groupPrices = $_product->getData();
        }
    }

    /* check group price exit or not */
    if (!is_null($groupPrices) || is_array($groupPrices)) {
        foreach ($groupPrices as $groupPrice) {
            if ($groupPrice['cust_group']) {
                echo $Groupprice = $groupPrice['NOT LOGGED IN'];
                echo $Groupprice;
                echo "<br/>";
                echo $GroupIds = $groupPrice['Wholesale'];
                echo $GroupIds;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for the help.